# problem in accessing data from sql in two drop down list at same time

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have two drop down list in web form..for both of them i've used following code to bind with sql..but whenever i'm trying to bind second drop down list with same method..it's giving error..
the code i've used:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

         if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            ddlPropertyType.AppendDataBoundItems = true;

            String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;

            String strQuery = "select ID, PropertyName from PropertyType";

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            cmd.CommandText = strQuery;

            cmd.Connection = con;

            try
            {

                con.Open();

                ddlPropertyType.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                ddlPropertyType.DataTextField = "PropertyName";

                ddlPropertyType.DataValueField = "ID";

                ddlPropertyType.DataBind();

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            finally
            {

                con.Close();

                con.Dispose();

            }

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create two dropdownlists with a dependency between them.
You need to enable AutoPostBack in the "parent" dropdownlist, add the changed event to it, and in the event load your "child" dropdownlist.

You have a good example here: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Creating-Cascading-DropDownLists-in-ASP.Net.aspx

Comment: am fetching data from two tables..say

Comment: am fetching data from two tables..say if i select state in first ddl i need all the city names in second ddl..how can this code be useful in fetching two tables at same time..

Answer (score 0):

u can directly bind dropdown using sql data base.......no need to do cding

Comment: i need to fetch cities on second drop down list on the basis of first..i tried that direct binding but it gave error as "Input string is not in correct format"

Comment: u just check auto postback property of dropdown set auto postback property true

Comment: SelectCommand="SELECT [city_id], [city_name] FROM [city_table] WHERE ([state_id] = @state_id)">.....................u can just apply this code in source code